# How can I start certmgr.msc for computer account?

Tags: windows, mmc

I can start individual Management Console snap-ins by starting them directly without going through starting `mmc.exe` and selecting the snap-ins I want.

However, for `certmgr.msc` selecting in MMC gives me the option to load `certmgr` for the computer account, which is usually what I need. How can I load `certmgr` for the computer account from the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save the `.msc` file to a file share and just call the UNC.

What I did was create the `.msc` file (as answered above) but I saved it to a network resource.  When I go to the next server, I can call the UNC via the RUN and done the local computer's certificate manager opens up as the Computer Account too.  I tested it across a couple different IIS boxes and found it was indeed unique and the computer's account.

```
\\fileserver\share\certmgr_computeraccount.msc
```

Answer (score 142):

If you have 2012R1/Win8 or later: You can use `certlm.msc` (**Cert**ificates **L**ocal **M**achine) instead of `certmgr.msc`. That will open the computer certificate store.

Comment: Thanks for this tip - copying certlm.msc from a Win8 machine is easier than creating a new msc file for my colleagues.

Comment: @ScottRhee, Are you sure that's going to work reliably?

Comment: @Pacerier, a few colleagues of mine tried that and I've got no problem so far.

Comment: A useful option of using `certlm.msc` over `certmgr.msc` is that it allows to change which computer's store you are working with.

Comment: @bmaupin: Yes; on the other hand, `.msc` files are XML files and are not signed, so you can drag the certlm.msc file from a 8/2012/10/2016 box to a 7/2008/Vista computer, and uses it there: it works exactly the same way there.

Answer (score 65):

The previous answer confused me until I found that a couple of steps were not explicitly stated. Whenever I opened certmgr.msc it only showed me the Current User certs, rather than the ones for the Local Computer store. I found more details in [this blog entry](http://chrisjakeway.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/windows-importing-a-certificate-for-a-service/).

In case that link dissolves, you need to do these steps to access the different stores:

1. Start → Run: `mmc.exe`
2. Menu: *File* → *Add/Remove Snap-in*…
3. Under *Available snap-ins*, select *Certificates* and press *Add*.
4. Select *Computer Account* for the certificates to manage.  Press *Next*.
5. Select *Local Computer* and press *Finish*.
6. Press *OK* to return to the management console.

Once you have the MMC set up, then you can save the msc with a new name per the above answer.

Comment: You need to be running `mmc` as an administrator to have step 4 available.

Comment: @tjmoore It's fine, once you have created the `.msc` file you do not need to load `mmc.exe` manually separately. I have gone a step further and added a shortcut to the `.msc` file to my Win+X menu. You need to adjust the options (File->Options) to put it in 'User mode' afterwards to prevent seeing the prompt to save changes constantly. Highlight Certificates in the left pane first to save you a navigation step every time you open it.

Answer (score 2):

Run `mmc`, select the snap-in, and save (*File → Save*) the console to your preferred location. Call it something like `syscertmgr.msc`. Run the saved console whenever you want the computer account's certificates.

Comment: That involves starting MMC. I need to open certmgr without starting MMC, i.e. whenever I connect to a server and install my cert, I want to be able just to start certmgr without going through MMC and selecting the snap-in and that ritual. I am looking for a shorter ritual. You are giving me a longer ritual.

Comment: @Andrew: However, you only need to do it *once*. The next time, your "ritual" would consist of 1) opening `syscertmgr.msc` that you created. You *cannot* force the built-in `certmgr.msc` do what it's not intended to do.

Comment: I only need to load the certificate once. On each server. We have four or five test environments for each production environments. I guess in the prod envs they actually update certs every year. But the test envs don't survive long enough so I'd never do that twice.

Comment: @Andrew: Fine, create a console once and start it from a network share. :) (To quote the Help file of `certmgr`, "To switch between managing certificates for your user account, a computer, or a service, you must have separate instances of Certificates added into the console." This means that `certmgr` _really cannot switch to Computer mode_.)

Comment: @Andrew: `certutil -ImportPFX`

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the instructions in @WiringHarness answer. On the 'Select Computer' screen, make sure you tick *"Allow the selected computer to be changed when launching from the command line. This only applies if you save the console."*

Let's imagine you save the console in your Windows user home directory with file name `certs.msc`.

The following batch script will allow you open the Certificates console on a remote machine as another user...

```
@echo off
set /p hostname="Enter host name: "
set /p username="Enter domain\username: "
runas /user:%username% "mmc %homepath%\certs.msc \"/computer:%hostname%\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .msc files are for the most part XML, you can create your own certlm.msc

Step 1) Make a copy of Certmgr.msc (copy certmgr.msc certlm.msc)
Step 2) open certlm.msc in the text editor of your choice (notepad certlm.msc)
Step 3) Change Line 88 in the file from:
-"Certificates - Current User"
-to:
-"Certificates - Local Computer"
Step 4) Save the file

Comment: So this is a hack then and you confirmed this works?

Comment: Well I learned something from this answer, but ultimately it's not correct because you can change the text to whatever you want, but it only changes the title of the snapin.