# I am not able to locate certificate created using makecert

Tags: windows, windows-10, certificate

I have just started learing to create certificates. I have created some & located in store using MMC.
But, when I tried this command , I was unable to locate certificate.

> makecert -n "CN=My Awesome Certificate Authority" -a sha1 -sv "MyCAuth
>   PrivateKey.pvk" -r "My Awesome Certificate Authority.cer"

But , when I specify the store name , I was able to locate the cetificate. Can someone explain. What is wrong with above command or what is the default value for -ss switch.

> makecert -n "CN=Test2" -a sha1 -sv "MyCAuth PrivateKey.pvk" -r "My
>   Awesome Certificate Authority.cer" -ss root

Answer (score 1):

In this condition, (or without -ss  switch) , certificate will be stored to a file in windows .

**File will be located the your working directory you run the tool from.**
If you run a cmd instance as admin, that ends up in `%SystemRoot%\system32`
 (or `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`), but this is not a constant. for, a non-admin instance defaults to `%UserProfile%`,

To install the certificate in store , we can just right click on .cer file to install , this will prompt you select the store location(CurrentUser/LocalMachine) and certificate store.
Now, you can verify the same using MMC console.

Thanks.

Comment: This is inaccurate: the file is located **in the working directory you ran the tool from**. If you run a cmd instance as admin, that ends up in `%SystemRoot%\system32` (or `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`), but **this is not a constant**. In fact, a non-admin instance defaults to `%UserProfile%`, but you can `cd` anywhere and the files will be dumped there. If you `cd C:\MyFavouriteFolder` and then `makecert` from there, your certificate and key will be located in `C:\MyFavouriteFolder`.

Comment: Great, I can upvote now :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check all certificate stores, for both local machine and your user.

From relevant question, [How can I start certmgr.msc for computer account?](https://superuser.com/a/390781/606970):

> 1)    Start → Run: mmc.exe
>   2)    Menu: File → Add/Remove Snap-in…
>   3)    Under Available snap-ins, select Certificates and press Add.
>   4)    Select Computer Account for the certificates to manage. Press Next.
>   5)    Select Local Computer and press Finish.
>   6)    Press OK to return to the management console.

Comment: I have already checked. No luck until I specify certificate store name explicitly using -ss.